# How to implement Google Analytics in android application?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to implement Google Analytics for my sample app in Android. How can I view the data or analytic changes in server & how can I send the custom variables to server side. What should I do after that?

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

  GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();

    // Start the tracker in manual dispatch mode...
    tracker.startNewSession("UA-34709489-1", this);
    tracker.trackPageView("/HomeScreen"); 
    // ...alternatively, the tracker can be started with a dispatch interval (in seconds).
    //tracker.startNewSession("UA-YOUR-ACCOUNT-HERE", 20, this);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button createEventButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewEventButton);
    createEventButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        tracker.trackEvent(
            "Clicks",  // Category
            "Button",  // Action
            "clicked", // Label
            77);       // Value
      }
    });

    Button createPageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewPageButton);
    createPageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        // Add a Custom Variable to this pageview, with name of "Medium" and value "MobileApp"
        tracker.setCustomVar(1, "Navigation Type", "Button click",2);
        tracker.trackPageView("/testApplicationHomeScreen");
      }
    });

    Button quitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.QuitButton);
    quitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
      }
    });

    Button dispatchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.DispatchButton);
    dispatchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        // Manually start a dispatch, not needed if the tracker was started with a dispatch
        // interval.
        tracker.dispatch();
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Stop the tracker when it is no longer needed.
    tracker.stopSession();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this: [Google Analytics For Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/)

In details, apart from including the analytic jar from the above link, you need to use the following code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker;

/**
 * @description Google analytics This class is used to create Google Analytics
 *              tracker instance. This will track actions performed in the
 *              application.
 */
 public final class GoogleAnalytics {

private static GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;
private static GoogleAnalytics googleAnalytics = null;
private final static int VALUE = -1;
private final static String CATEGORY = "Application Name";

/**
 * 
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public static GoogleAnalytics getGoogleAnalyticsInstance(Context context) {
    if (googleAnalytics == null) {
        googleAnalytics = new GoogleAnalytics(context);
        tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
        tracker.startNewSession(--enter your reg number here--, 10, context);
    }
    return googleAnalytics;

}

private GoogleAnalytics(Context context) {
}

/**
 * Stop current session
 */
public void stopSession() {
    tracker.stopSession();
    googleAnalytics = null;
}

/**
 * Tracks Event of actions performed
 * 
 * @param action
 * @param label
 */
public void trackEvent(String action, String label) {
    tracker.trackEvent(CATEGORY, // Category
            action, // Action
            label, // Label
            VALUE);
}
   }
```

Now anywhere you need to track an event just call:

```
GoogleAnalytics.getGoogleAnalyticsInstance(this).trackEvent("Event Name", "Event Desc");
```

To get your application registraion number see this:
[Register for Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Also remeber to call following when you want a single session to end:

```
GoogleAnalytics.getGoogleAnalyticsInstance(this).stopSession();
```

Comment: i have tried but didnt useful

Comment: what problem are you getting?

Comment: How can i use this code? shall i call this class in my other activity

Comment: yup. using the code line mentioned at the end.

Comment: i have called your code in onclick of button in myactivity but after that what should i do