# How to implement Google Analytics v4 on a Project in Android Studion imported from legacy Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, google-analytics

My legacy application project doesn't have Application class.
So, the [**official document**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#tracking-methods) doesn't help.
I don't know where the following code should go:

```
/**
 * Enum used to identify the tracker that needs to be used for tracking.
 *
 * A single tracker is usually enough for most purposes. In case you do need multiple trackers,
 * storing them all in Application object helps ensure that they are created only once per
 * application instance.
 */
public enum TrackerName {
  APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
  GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
  ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
}

HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();
```

And these code:

```
synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
  if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

    GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
        : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
            : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
    mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

  }
  return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}
```

I have imported these libs of googleAnalytics.

[image]

But I still can't import libs like [**this way**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364688/how-to-implement-google-analytics-in-android-application):

```
import com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker;
```

And, because I am using Android Studio 1.2 Beta3, [**the tutorial based on Eclipse**](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-analytics-v4-example/) also not suit for my case.

## Is there any simple way to implement Google Analytics on Android app? Like initialising in iOS?

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
  [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
  [[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
  [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-Y"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simples complete implementation of Analytics on Android requires:

1. Link to Google Play Services (It looks like you already have this done)
2. Add the [required network permissions](https://github.com/googleanalytics/hello-world-android-app/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L6) in your app manifest.
3. [Extend Android Application class](https://github.com/googleanalytics/hello-world-android-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/googleanalyticshelloworld/MyApp.java#L14), [override onCreate](https://github.com/googleanalytics/hello-world-android-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/googleanalyticshelloworld/MyApp.java#L46) and set your [app class implementation in the <android name='you_app_class'> name](https://github.com/googleanalytics/hello-world-android-app/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L14) attribute.
4. In onCreate [create new tracker](https://github.com/googleanalytics/hello-world-android-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/googleanalyticshelloworld/MyApp.java#L51) and keep it in static var tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).newTracker(); Enable automatic reporting for [screens, exceptions](https://github.com/googleanalytics/hello-world-android-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/googleanalyticshelloworld/MyApp.java#L54), etc.
5. Register [AnalyticsReceiver & AnalyticsService](https://github.com/googleanalytics/hello-world-android-app/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L34) in your Application Manifest.

Google Analytics has a github project with the simplest [Analytics hello world all](https://github.com/googleanalytics/hello-world-android-app). It show the bare minimum needed for correct reporting on Android.